# What is a hard apple cider expiration date

Tags: cider

The recipe uses store bought apple juice with no added preservatives or additives.

The store bought juice has an expiration date of April 2014.

Will the cider expire on this date also, or has the process of turning it into alcohol changed the expiration date?

Another thing is if the juice was passed its expiration date before making the cider will that be an issue? The juice tasted fine and I have had a sample of the cider and it tastes really good.

Here is the steps to make it.

Recipe here:

21L Juice (7bottles)

Yeast Nutrient (Boil up raisins (that don’t have sulphite on them) and small amount of water, mash up the raisins and simmer)

10- 14Cup’s corn sugar or dextrose (the more sugar the more kick it will have)

1 Lalvin EC1118 Yeast

Steps
1.Boil up yeast nutrient and mash up raisins

2.Take out a little juice from the bottle and add sugar.

3.Shake out the sugar(even do this for the fermenter batch as it saves time and stirring)

4.Put in the yeast nutrient(make sure that it isn’t still too hot) and shake the bottle

5.Add the yeast and shake the bottle a. If you are making a fermenter size batch then 
pour it all in the fermenter

6.Leave that until the fermenter has stopped bubbling and leave for a few days.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have sanitized everything carefully and you bottle condition, then your cider will have a shelf life of several years. You will most likely have drunk it all before it goes bad...

Comment: So even if the juice was expired before I made the cider? What do you mean by "You bottle condition"?

Comment: If the juice has expired you run the risk of bacterial or fungal contamination. Fermenting won't fix it. If it's infected you'll know from the taste and smell.

Comment: Bottle conditioning is the process of adding a small amount of sugar to the finished cider before placing it in pressure resistant bottles. The sugar ferments, producing carbon dioxide which carbonates (conditions) the beer. Take a look at the chapter in [How to Brew](http://www.howtobrew.com/section1/chapter11.html) about bottling beer. The process for cider is identical.

Comment: Thanks @TobiasPatton I have never heard it called that before. I have always heard it as priming or simply carbonating.